# How to call key of object inside of callback?

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

How can i get *variable* in *handler* function of *obj*? Without reference of the *obj* in *MyClass*.

```
    var obj = {
        func: function(){
            var myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.handler = this.handler;
            myClass.play();        
        },

        handler: function(){
            //Here i don't have access to obj
            console.log(this); //MyClass
            console.log(this.variable); //undefined
        },

        variable:true
    };

    function MyClass(){
        this.play = function(){
            this.handler();
        };

        this.handler = function(){};
    };

    obj.func();
```

​
That's construction need you, if you use Base.js or another similar way of oop.

_.bindAll(obj) (underscore metod) also not suitable. It's break overriding in Base.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind only handler method: http://jsfiddle.net/uZN3e/1/

```
var obj = {
    variable:true,

    func: function(){
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        // notice Function.bind call here
        // you can use _.bind instead to make it compatible with legacy browsers
        myClass.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
        myClass.play();        
    },

    handler: function(){
        console.log(this.variable);
    }
};

function MyClass(){
    this.play = function(){
        this.handler();
    };

    this.handler = function(){};
};

obj.func();
​
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to refer original context:

```
...
var self = this;
myClass.handler = function(){ self.handler(); };
...
```

Comment: Hmmm, i don't think so. You suggest define _handler_ inside of _func_ function. But if _func_ will be have many listeners, and these listeners will be massive, you will get very big function. I think it's bad tone of programming.

Comment: In fact, `Function.bind` is using kind of the same thing and is also bad to performance. You need to structure your code in a way that will not need bindings like this. https://gist.github.com/2301514 – you do create a closure (a function) for each of the bound functions and you do put context object within that closure. So this answer is also valid and being more obvious to the developer, might be actually better (depending on your needs)

Comment: You're right, about performance. But what to do with "But if func will be have many listeners, and these listeners will be massive, you will get very big function"? You think large functions it's ok?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I'd be happy to see an example of these "many listeners" and a very big function and why that would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `variable` before `handler`:

```
var obj = {
    variable: true, 

    func: function(){
        // ...       
    },

    handler: function(){
        console.log(this.variable); //true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Function call with this from obj in declared in a scope var to solve it.

```
var obj = {
    func: function(){
        var self = this;
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.handler = function() { return this.handler.call(self); };
        myClass.play();        
    },

    handler: function(){
        //Here i don't have access to obj
        console.log(this); //MyClass
        console.log(this.variable); //undefined
    },

    variable:true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to *obj* because *this* is bind to the instance of MyClass constructor - myClass. If in *handler* you want to have access to *myClass* through *this* and access to *obj* you have to use *obj* name directly so:

```
console.log(this); // myClass
console.log(obj.variable); // true
```

If you want to have *this* bind to *obj* use what Juan Mellado or gryzzly suggested.